# Downgrade Python from 3.11.2 to 3.10 in specifc environment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python's virtual environment 'venv'. My current version is 3.11.2

I need to downgrade it.

I have already tried the following steps:

```
pip3 install python==3.10.10
```

and got the following error:

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python==3.10.10 (from versions: none)**

**ERROR: No matching distribution found for python==3.10.10**

I also tried for lower versions like 3.8.0, 3.9.0, ... Allways same error.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use pip to install Python itself; it's only for Python libraries.

Comment: By contrast, this is something you can do with [Nix](https://nixos.org)

Comment: Is there a way without using 3rd party libraries?

Comment: Download the Python version of your choice from the official website and install it…?! Or use some package manager which may or may not be available on your OS?!

Comment: Also, virtual environments are designed to be cheap and easy to replace. Rather than downgrading an existing virtual environment, discard it (or ignore it) and create a new one with the required version of Python.

Comment: Here is a useful link, that I thin k would help you downgrade your version. https://chris35wills.github.io/conda_python_version/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## To answer your question directly

Try python.org.

Head straight to https://www.python.org/downloads/ to download the distribution you want.

### If I am to guess what problem you are facing, here are some details

When you are running your command prompt, make sure you know which python you are executing. Example:

```
PS C:\Users\jli8\pythonWork\dpr-data-presenter> conda activate p310
(p310) PS C:\Users\jli8\pythonWork\dpr-data-presenter> .\venv\Scripts\activate
(venv) (p310) PS C:\Users\jli8\pythonWork\dpr-data-presenter> where.exe python
C:\Users\jli8\pythonWork\dpr-data-presenter\venv\Scripts\python.exe
C:\Users\jli8\Anaconda3\envs\p310\python.exe
C:\Users\jli8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
C:\Users\jli8\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

(venv) (p310) PS C:\Users\jli8\pythonWork\dpr-data-presenter>
```

From my terminal above, I actually have 3 pythons.

- Python3.11 installed in AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
- Python3.10 installed in Anaconda env "p310"
- (which I used to create venv), finally the last venv in use with is in my working folder dpr-data-presenter\venv\Scripts\python.exe

From this limited context here, the most straightforward answer to you would be just download python3.10.10 from python.org. Make sure you understand how to execute from that python3.10.10 that you have installed and create your `venv` from that python3.10.10.

Some helpful reference for you:
https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a software that can manage python executable. pip manages python packages. If it's not clear, python is not a package.

[The doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/)

> pip is the package installer for Python. You can use it to install packages from the Python Package Index and other indexes.

I will present you some solutions for your needs:

- [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv): this a manager for python version. It's lightweight and easy. This is the most straightforward way (opinion here)
- [nix](https://github.com/NixOS/nix): (proposed by [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)) this is a general development environment manager. This is widely used and is also lightweight. Also it's quite easy to set. This is ideal if you want to manage other dependencies other than your Python version (external libraries, software)
- [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/): this is the most used Python environment manager. conda is **heavy** - it installs a bunch of things - and gave headache. Although, it would be the most documented manager - in terms for troubleshooting, I am not referring to its actual documentation. It works well on Windows. This is a good choice if you just want Python running and you are an absolute beginner in programming in general. Note: there are lightweight version of conda such as miniconda, mamba and so on.
- [docker](https://www.docker.com/) (and other containers solution): this is an advanced option. Also, arguably it's the best way to reproduce your development environment.  It needs you to dive into a lot of details if you want to customize it. This is a good choice if you are kind of experimented at interacting with your Linux OS **and** you have third-party library dependencies that can be a pain (CUDA for GPU, for example) **and** your code should be moved to a node/cluster/server to perform costly computation.

This is not exhaustive also those approach can be cumulative: docker images can have conda or other manager installed on it, you can use a nix env with a pyenv/conda installed inside and so on. I would advise to take the fastest and the lightest solution for your solution. Then, if you need a more powerful (heavy) environment manager, you can move to something else.

Comment: I'd argue that Nix does a better job of creating Docker images than Docker itself does. You don't know that running the same Dockerfile twice will install the same packages, because Dockerfiles often have steps that pull unpinned dependencies off the network; because everything in Nix is hash-addressed and only build steps that can declare their output hash ahead of time are allowed network access, it solves that comprehensively.

Comment: Interesting, I do not use Nix. Your comment is a valuable addition to balance the list. Thanks!